# Flutter: Results from Data Sorting (from Array Data) do not Appear in the ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I use arrays to store 'Market location data' and I save the data in the file Data.dart

**Data.dart**

```
class Market{
  static List dataMarket = [
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Alfamart',
        latitudeDest: -6.163891,
        longitudeDest: 106.628915),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Minis'
        latitudeDest: -6.211269,
        longitudeDest: 106.615574),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Star Market'
        latitudeDest: -6.223254,
        longitudeDest:  106.703905),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Allmark'
        latitudeDest: -6.163891,
        longitudeDest: 106.628915),
    Data(
        nameDest = 'Eig Store'
        latitudeDest: -6.178293, 
        longitudeDest: 106.631862),
  ];
}

class Data{
  String nameDest;
  var latitudeDest;
  var longitudeDest;


  Data({
     this.nameDest
     this.latitudeDest,
     this.longitudeDest});
}
```

and i use that 'Market location data' for getting calculate distance between user and market. and I also want to display from the nearest market order

**MyListMarket.dart**

```
import 'package:example/Data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class TabMarket extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _TabMarketState createState() => _TabMarketState();
}

class _TabMarketState extends State<TabMarket> {
  var lastLatitude;
  var lastLongitude;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initUserLocation();
  }


  Future<void> _initUserLocation() async {
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator()
          .getLastKnownPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
      lastLatitude = position.latitude;
      lastLongitude = position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Permission Denied");
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dataInstance = Market.dataMarket;
    var newSortRange = [];

    if (lastLatitude == null || lastLongitude == null){
      for(int i = 0; i >= dataInstance.length; i++) {
        newSortRange[i] = 0;
      }
    }else{for (int i = 0; i >= dataInstance.length; i++) {
      //calculating distance with lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2

      var p = 0.017453292519943295;
      var c = cos;
      var a = 0.5 - c((dataInstance[i].latitudeDest - lastLatitude) * p) / 2 +
              c(lastLatitude * p) * c(dataInstance[i].latitudeDest * p) *
              (1 - c((dataInstance[i].longitudeDest - lastLongitude) * p)) / 2;
      newSortRange[i] = 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
    }}
    newSortRange.sort();
    //i wanna sort this data from the smallest number
    //already tried with newSortRange.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(246, 246, 246, 1),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initUserLocation(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return ListView.separated(
              key: PageStorageKey<String>('aKey'),
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: newSortRange.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                return Material(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(251, 251, 251, 1),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Text(dataInstance[index].nameDest)
                        trailing: Text(newSortRange[index].toStringAsFixed(2) +
                            "\nKM",
                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 13,),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
                      ),
                    ],),);
              },

              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(
                  height: 0.0,
                  thickness: 0.7,
                );
              }
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

so I tried to calculate the distance with the for loop and save it into a new array

my code have no error, but not appear anything only blank without list view.
maybe the method for storing data into an array is wrong?
How i can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your _initUserLocation method is async, so even you call in initstate then also you can not calculate other values base on that in build method because at that _initUserLocation method could not complete its task.

In future builder you have to calculate everything where you can see actual data because future builder give data when process is complete.

You have to return any data from future method so that futurebuilder can understand now method complete calculation.

i made many changes in your code, which is working fine.

Let me know it works for you or not and also feel free to ask any questions if you don't understand any part of code.

Full Working Demo:

```
 class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  var lastLatitude;
  var lastLongitude;
  final dataInstance = Market.dataMarket;
  var newSortRange = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_initUserLocation();
  }

  Future<int> _initUserLocation() async {
    try {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      Position position = await Geolocator()
             .getLastKnownPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
      lastLatitude = position.latitude;
      lastLongitude = position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Permission Denied");
    }
    return 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(246, 246, 246, 1),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initUserLocation(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          if (lastLatitude == null || lastLongitude == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataInstance.length; i++) {
              newSortRange[i] = 0;
            }
          } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataInstance.length; i++) {
              //calculating distance with lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2

              var p = 0.017453292519943295;
              var c = cos;
              var a = 0.5 -
                  c((dataInstance[i].latitudeDest - lastLatitude) * p) / 2 +
                  c(lastLatitude * p) *
                      c(dataInstance[i].latitudeDest * p) *
                      (1 -
                          c((dataInstance[i].longitudeDest - lastLongitude) *
                              p)) /
                      2;
              newSortRange.add(12742 * asin(sqrt(a)));
            }
          }
          newSortRange.sort();
          print(newSortRange);
          return ListView.separated(
              key: PageStorageKey<String>('aKey'),
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: newSortRange.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Material(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(251, 251, 251, 1),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        trailing: Text(
                          newSortRange[index].toStringAsFixed(2) + "\nKM",
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(
                  height: 0.0,
                  thickness: 0.7,
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Market {
  static List dataMarket = [
    Data(latitudeDest: -6.163891, longitudeDest: 106.628915),
    Data(latitudeDest: -6.211269, longitudeDest: 106.615574),
    Data(latitudeDest: -6.223254, longitudeDest: 106.703905),
    Data(latitudeDest: -6.163891, longitudeDest: 106.628915),
    Data(latitudeDest: -6.178293, longitudeDest: 106.631862),
  ];
}

class Data {
  var latitudeDest;
  var longitudeDest;

  Data({this.latitudeDest, this.longitudeDest});
}
```

Comment: what if I have a 'name' for that market and want it to be displayed in sync with the newSortRange data? can i store calculate distance to dataMarket array?

Comment: you can create a new variable in class and save datadistance in it. now, you have to use custom sorting method, so that you can have control over index and also change index of dataInstance. Accept my answer if it work for you!